# How to make DrawerToggle overlay the ActionBar?

Tags: android, android-actionbar, navigation-drawer

I want to implement my app with DrawerToggle and ActionBar (support v4). I need the toggle overlay actionBar as like as Google Play Store in this http://prntscr.com/90nl4n.

How can i do? Every suggestion will be highly appreciated. Thanks in advance
Here is my layout:

```
<RelativeLayout
    android:id="@+id/layoutRoot"
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/tvTabDivider"
        style="@style/divider"/>

    <android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout
        android:id="@+id/slidingMenu"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">

        <FrameLayout
            android:id="@+id/realtabcontent"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"/>

        <!-- Sliding menu -->
        <ScrollView
            android:id="@+id/sv_slidingMenu"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_gravity="start"
            android:background="@mipmap/bg_left_menu">

            <RelativeLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:background="@drawable/bg_blur_left_menu">

                <RelativeLayout
                    android:id="@+id/v_account"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
                    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
                    android:paddingBottom="10dp"
                    android:paddingTop="10dp">

                    <ImageView
                        android:id="@+id/iv_avatar"
                        style="@style/imageview_normal"
                        android:layout_width="@dimen/height_avatar_menu"
                        android:layout_height="@dimen/height_avatar_menu"
                        android:layout_centerVertical="true"
                        android:layout_gravity="center"
                        android:padding="8dp"
                        android:scaleType="centerCrop"
                        android:src="@mipmap/img_logo"
                        app:border="true"
                        app:border_color="@color/white"
                        app:border_width="1dp"/>

                    <LinearLayout
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_centerVertical="true"
                        android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
                        android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/iv_avatar"
                        android:orientation="vertical">

                        <TextView
                            android:id="@+id/tv_login"
                            style="@style/text_normal.bold.white"
                            android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
                            android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
                            android:background="@drawable/bg_circle_line_white"
                            android:gravity="left"
                            android:text="@string/login"/>

                        <TextView
                            android:id="@+id/tv_account_info"
                            style="@style/text_normal.bold.white"
                            android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
                            android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
                            android:background="@drawable/bg_circle_line_white"
                            android:drawableLeft="@mipmap/ic_setting"
                            android:drawablePadding="8dp"
                            android:gravity="left"
                            android:text="@string/acccount_info"
                            android:visibility="gone"/>
                    </LinearLayout>
                </RelativeLayout>

                <LinearLayout
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_below="@+id/v_account"
                    android:orientation="vertical">

                    <TextView
                        android:id="@+id/tvSearch"
                        style="@style/styleTextInfo"
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:background="@drawable/selector_menu_bg"
                        android:drawableLeft="@mipmap/ic_search_left_menu"
                        android:drawablePadding="5dp"
                        android:gravity="center_vertical"
                        android:text="@string/search"
                        android:textColor="@color/white"/>

                    <TextView
                        android:id="@+id/tvPostNews"
                        style="@style/styleTextInfo"
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:background="@drawable/selector_menu_bg"
                        android:drawableLeft="@mipmap/ic_post_news_left_menu"
                        android:drawablePadding="5dp"
                        android:gravity="center_vertical"
                        android:text="@string/post_news_letter_fragment"
                        android:textColor="@color/white"/>

                    <TextView
                        android:id="@+id/tvSalon"
                        style="@style/styleTextInfo"
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:background="@drawable/selector_menu_bg"
                        android:drawableLeft="@mipmap/ic_salon_left_menu"
                        android:drawablePadding="5dp"
                        android:gravity="center_vertical"
                        android:text="@string/salon"
                        android:textColor="@color/white"/>
                </LinearLayout>
            </RelativeLayout>
        </ScrollView>
    </android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout>

</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: What have you tried so far? Have you already looked at sample projects such as [cheesesquare](https://github.com/chrisbanes/cheesesquare)?

Comment: @ianhanniballake: Hi, i'm using Toolbar as your suggestion library, but i can't assign the action bar which i've done to the toolbar :(